# How do I make a default on circuit the can latch off until a interrupt goes low?

Tags: low-power, latch

I am trying to design a datalogger that should run for a long time on one set of batteries. I have a RTC module that has a interrupt wire that is high when powered on and goes low when a alarm time occurs. When this happens I want to power on the main circuit, measure and then send a signal from the arduino to power off again.

I have tried to just run via a p-channel mosfet, but my electrical engineering skills are not sufficient to design a latch circuit for it. I didn't manage to get it to turn on when the power turns on...

I would be thankful for some help. [image: nearly working circuit]

Comment: 1. Schematic or block diagram please? 2. How long does the interrupt from the RTC last? 3. How often does it repeat? 4.How long does a measurement take? 5. Is there an output from the "main circuit" that indicates the end of a measurement? 6. What's the relationship between the "data logger" and the "main circuit"?

Comment: I added my simulation circuit. The interrupt lasts for 1 second. The measurement is fast, but it might take more than a second to start the ic and do the measurement. The arduino will have one output dedicated to doing the power off.

Comment: You'll also need a signal of some sort to the Arduino to let it know that the measurement has been started/made so that it'll know when to turn off whatever it's supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit should do what you want:

[image]

IC2 represents your RTC module; I just picked one with an IRQ output.

When the IRQ line goes low, the latch (IC1) is set (pin 3 high).  Pin 6 is then low, which turns on the P-channel MOSFET nd supplies power to the main circuit.

When the Arduino sets its output low, the latch will reset, and the power will be turned off.

(Note: I didn't include the decoupling caps on each of the IC's, they should have 100 nF caps between Vcc and ground.)